# Importing GDB WKB geometry error (OGR Geometry Factory err:6)

Tags: postgis, ogr, file-geodatabase, well-known-binary

I have prepared all my layers in File GDB (converted the projection to EPSG3857) and uploaded the entire File GDB to PostGIS.

Somehow, it returned errors described below
[image]

Yet, it is uploaded to my PostGIS server and seemed to work just fine.

The error messages though, are those just an eyesore? Or a critical issue?

Comment: Please copy the **text** of the error message(s) into your post. This will assure that it's 1) legible to those from whom you want assistance, no matter what device is being used, 2) free-text searchable, so that others can find your question.

Comment: The feature class will be there, that's individual feature errors, row numbers will be OBJECTIDs from your file geodatabase. These features may have null geometries or be otherwise invalid. SDE doesn't allow geometry errors but I don't know if that's inherited from PostGIS or imposed by SDE.. have a look at those rows in the file geodatabase and see if you can find why the import doesn't like them - and also check if these *individual rows* have actually been imported so the error can be treated as a warning or are missing, needing some fixing before importing.

Comment: If your geometries inculde the North or South pole, transformation to EPSG:3857 will fail for mathematical reasons.

Comment: They were just warning. nothing critical. using repair geometry in ArcMap solved the issues